# Does reverse causality from Z to Y violate exclusion restriction in IV?

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variables, reverse-causality

I am estimating the effect of endogenous X on Y using 2SLS estimator with an instrument variable (Z).

- X: Safety net program participation (binary), designed to increase household income
- Y: Household income
- Z: Generosity of program eligibility

I tested my Z is relevant (passed weak IV test), and I think Z affects Y only through X; generosity of program eligibility affect income only through program participation.

However, I am concerned about possible reverse causality. When the economy is bad and households are suffering from low income, government relaxes program eligibility so more people can participate in the program.

I have two questions regarding this.

1. Does this reverse causality from Y -> X violate the exclusion restriction of my IV?
2. Since there's no formal way to test exclusion restriction, I plotted a graph of Y and Z over time, and showed that Z did not respond to Y. (Z has been steadily increasing even during the recession when Y significantly went down) Would it be one way to defend the validity of my IV?

Thank you.